# Can't Delete File On Terminal

Tags: emacs, terminal

Please, open File 1 to access the problem. If I type it here some important characters that I believe to be what's causing the drama won't show on the post. Thank you!

I basically created a file that I can't get rid of.

Screen shoot of what I have done
[image: Screen shoot of what I have done]

Comment: Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow. You may be able to get help on Super User.

Comment: Tangentially, did you really mean to *suspend* those `less` jobs, instead of quitting? You have two independent suspended invocations of `less index.html~` in that screenshot, which is a bit pointless. You can quit `less` with `q`. You were presumably typing `C-z`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Space, `<`, and `>` are all treated specially by your shell.

Because of that, you'll need to quote the name. Try this:

```
rm 'index.html <RET>'
```

Comment: You're also a bit lucky `index.html` didn't get accidentally deleted. It didn't (I think) because `<RET>` was causing your shell to look for a file `RET` to use as standard input, and because of the syntax error of ending a command immediately after `>` (it expects a filename to use for standard output after that).

Answer (score 1):

In cases where you can't figure out how to quote/escape the filename appropriately, a convenient approach is:

```
rm -i index.html*
```

You will be prompted (because of the `-i` option) to delete each filename matching the specified glob pattern, one at a time.  Simply answer `y` to the ones you want to delete.

Quoting the arguments correctly is safest (it avoids any possibility of accidentally deleting something you didn't mean to delete), so I recommend always doing so when you can; but if you've managed to generate a really garbled filename (Unix places very few constraints upon filenames) then this method can be very useful.